# Adding programmatically an inline defined in XAML

Tags: wpf

I have a FlowDocument. Is it possible to add an inline into it but the inline is defined in XAML. E.g.

```
<FlowDocument >
  <Paragraph Name="Output"/>
</FlowDocument>

var AppendTo = new Span();
var XAML = "<Run>Something</Run>";
AppendTo.Inlines.Add(XAML); // This is what I mean - adding elements using XAML
Output.Inlines.Add(AppendTo);
```

Thank you

Note - to those who vote to close it because it's too broad. Maybe read the answer that I marked as answer and then think where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, its possible but the *how* depends on the scope where the document is defined. In the visual tree or as a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an actual `Run` element, or any other kind of element, from a XAML string programmatically using the `XamlReader.Parse` method:

```
var AppendTo = new Span();
var pc = new System.Windows.Markup.ParserContext();
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
var run= System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<Run>Something</Run>", pc) as Run;
AppendTo.Inlines.Add(run);
Output.Inlines.Add(AppendTo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. It's easier when you assign a name to all relevant elements.

### `FlowDocument` is defined as a resource of a `Control`

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <FlowDocument x:Key="Document">
      <Paragraph Name="Inline" />
    </FlowDocument>
  </Window.Resources>
```

In the code-behind file of the `Control` you can use the [`FrameworkElement.TryFindResource(object) : object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tryfindresource?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.FrameworkElement.TryFindResource);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) or [`FrameworkElement.FindResource(object) : object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=netframework-4.8) to sear through the control's resource:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (TryFindResource("Document") is FlowDocument document)
  {
    foreach (Block documentBlock in document.Blocks)
    {
      if (documentBlock is Paragraph paragraph || documentBlock.Name.Equals("Inline", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        // Do something with the Paragraph
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### `FlowDocument` is defined as element of the `Control`'s visual tree

```
<Window>
  <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <RichTextBox>
      <RichTextBox.Document>
        <FlowDocument x:Name="Document">
          <Paragraph Name="Inline" />
        </FlowDocument>
      </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code-behind just access the elements by its name. Every element that has a `Name` value assigned is accessible via the auto-generated field reference:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Paragraph paragraph = this.Inline;
  // Do something with the Paragraph
}
```

The `VisualTreeHelper` can also be used to traverse the viaual tree and search for the document or inline element,

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I wasn't asking this but what mm8 answered. Anyway, thank you for the attempt to help. :-)